# How to change msbuild working directory in TFS 2013 workflow

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild

I have a TFS 2013 build xaml workflow, that eventually calls the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities.MSBuild activity once for each solution that I want to build. When msbuild.exe is called, it's working directory is the working directory of the current solution being built. I can see this through the 'MSBuildStartupDirectory' property when running msbuild with a 'diagnostic' verbosity.

Unfortunately, I need the working of msbuild.exe to be somewhere else when msbuild.exe starts. This is because I use the MSBuild SonarQube runner that imposes constraints on the directory from which msbuild is called.

I have looked at the 'msbuild' activity and there is no way to control the working directory. Is there another way to control the working directory of this activity?

Answer (score 0):

Its been a while since I edited a build process template but I believe you could use an activity that just executes a command in CMD and provide the full MSBuild command.  I'm sure there are tons of variables you will need to setup for this to work.

Instead of editing the build process template have you considered using a PowerShell script in the Post-build script to execute SonarQube?

[image]

Comment: Good suggestion for the CMD. But if I need to go through the path of modifying the workflow, I would rather replace a lot of the activities by a call to a powershell script that would do everything (start sonarQube runner, compile, test, stop SonarQube runner). This would simplify the workflow and put most of the build logic in my PowerShell script. I am not there yet but I seriously consider it.

Comment: We have always avoided changing the build process templates so we didn't have to "own" them long term.  We have been able to use MSBuild or the Pre/Post-build scripts to extend TFS builds successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't found any way to control the working directory of msbuild. But since I know that the working directory will be the directory of the project being built by msbuild, I created a new proj file at the root of my workspace (where my working directory has to be) and only build this new proj file from my workflow. This new proj file then builds all my other solutions. That way, my working directory is the same for all the solutions being built.

Here is an example of my top level proj file:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Build">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Solutions Include="**\*.sln"/>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="Build">
    <MSBuild Projects="@(Solutions)" Targets="Build"/>
  </Target>      
</Project>
```

But beware that doing this may affect the output directory (OutDir) given to each solution. So you may want to do something like this:

```
<MSBuild Projects="@(Solutions)" Targets="Build" Properties="OutDir=$(OutDir)..\%(Solutions.Filename)"/>
```